# Cannot create records from rails seeds, fails with undefined method `generated_methods?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-2

I recently upgraded an app from rails 2.3.18 to rails 3.2.1 and I'm trying to fully migrate it.

When I run rake db:seeds, it fails with:

```
 undefined method `generated_methods?' for WhateverObject
```

This is the content of a very basic seed file:

```
[ 'MTW', 'GBP', 'USD', 'EUR' ].each do |currency|
  binding.pry
  Currency.find_or_create_by_code(currency)
end
```

Through pry, I noticed that I cannot call any of the methods like:

```
Currency.new Currency.create
```

I also tried with:

```
Currency.where(code: currency).first_or_create

Currency.column_names
=> ["id", "code", "rate"]
```

What's wrong here?

Stack trace:

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `generated_methods?' for Currency(id: integer, code: string, rate: decimal):Class
/home/bogdan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:55:in `method_missing'
/home/bogdan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/szilm-validates_timeliness-2.3.1/lib/validates_timeliness/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:46:in `define_attribute_methods_with_timeliness'
/home/bogdan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:168:in `respond_to?'
/home/bogdan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:81:in `block in assign_attributes'
/home/bogdan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `each'
/home/bogdan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `assign_attributes'
/home/bogdan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:294:in `block in find_or_instantiator_by_attributes'
/home/bogdan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/base.rb:500:in `initialize'
/home/bogdan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:293:in `new'
/home/bogdan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:293:in `find_or_instantiator_by_attributes'
/home/bogdan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:52:in `method_missing'
/home/bogdan/projects/%^&^*&/webapp/db/seeds/currencies.seeds.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/bogdan/projects/$%^%&*/webapp/db/seeds/currencies.seeds.rb:2:in `each'
/home/bogdan/projects/&^*&*&/webapp/db/seeds/currencies.seeds.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/home/bogdan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/home/bogdan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
/home/bogdan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/bogdan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/home/bogdan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/bogdan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What attributes are defined on the model?

Comment: @japed I edited my question.

Comment: @Зелёный no they're not, you can do `find_or_create_by_code` [rails 3 guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.21/active_record_querying.html#dynamic-finders) but in rails 4 it would be `find_or_create_by(code: "blah")`

Comment: @japed I see the seedbank gem is installed. could this cause it?

Comment: I'm not sure, but looking at [apidock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/ClassMethods/generated_methods%3F) the method was deprecated so doesn't exist in rails 3.  I'd definitely try removing the seedbank gem and see if it works then.

Comment: can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @thaleshcv there it is :)

Comment: @japed I removed seedbank, no success..

Comment: Post your model code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your issue is caused by [outdated validates_timeliness](https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness/issues/8#issuecomment-216392) gem (you have 2.3.1 version).

Try upgrading to version 3.x:

> in your Gemfile

```
gem 'validates_timeliness', '~> 3.0'
```

and then, run as usual:

```
$ bundle install
```

Comment: Great, it was from gem 'szilm-validates_timeliness' which required 'validates_timeliness' gem.